# flutter copy with error: The named parameter 'id' isn't defined undefined_named_parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I work  to consume  data  from API. but when I add class  Site I get this error in copyWith.

```
** copywith error: The named parameter 'id' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter **
** copywith error: The named parameter 'name' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter **
** copywith error: The named parameter 'city' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter **
** copywith error: The named parameter 'address' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter **
```

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


class Site {


  Site(this.id,this.name,this.address,this.city);
  String id;
  String name;
  String address;
  String city;

  Site.JSON({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.address,
    this.city
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if(id != null){
      map['id'] = id;
    }
    map['name'] = name;
    map['ville'] = name;
    return map;
  }
 Site copyWith({
    String id,
    String name,
    String address,
    String city,
  }) =>
      Site(
        id : id ?? this.id,//error line 
        name : name ?? this.name, //error line 
        address : address ?? this.address, //error line 
        city : city ?? this.city, //error line//error line 
       );
  // Extract a Site object from a Map object
  Site.fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    this.id = map['id'];
    this.name = map['name'];
    this.city = map['city'];
  }

  // toString Method
  String toString(){
    return  ' / ' + this.name + ' / ' + this.city;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "city": city,
    "name": name,
    "address":address
  };
  factory Site.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Site.JSON(
     id: json["id"],
     city: json["city"],
     name: json["name"],
    address: json["address"],

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


class Site {


  String id;
  String name;
  String address;
  String city;

 Site({this.id,this.name,this.address,this.city});

  Site.JSON({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.address,
    this.city
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if(id != null){
      map['id'] = id;
    }
    map['name'] = name;
    map['ville'] = name;
    return map;
  }
 Site copyWith({
    String id,
    String name,
    String address,
    String city,
  }) =>
      Site(
        id : id ?? this.id,//error line 
        name : name ?? this.name, //error line 
        address : address ?? this.address, //error line 
        city : city ?? this.city, //error line//error line 
       );
  // Extract a Site object from a Map object
  Site.fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    this.id = map['id'];
    this.name = map['name'];
    this.city = map['city'];
  }

  // toString Method
  String toString(){
    return  ' / ' + this.name + ' / ' + this.city;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "city": city,
    "name": name,
    "address":address
  };
  factory Site.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Site.JSON(
     id: json["id"],
     city: json["city"],
     name: json["name"],
    address: json["address"],

  );




 
}
```

Comment: thank you ,it working fine now .but why I have this error please?

Answer (score -1):

The method is named `copyWith` and the callback seems to be using `copywith`.